# iCarouselTypeLinear with more than 6 images

Tags: ios, icarousel

for some reason when I set `iCarousel.type =  iCarouselTypeLinear`, I can't use more than 6 images. When I try to scroll I get the following error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa47c2b0'
```

What am I missing?

Any help will be really appreciated.

Controller Code:

```
journalCarouselItems = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon-JCO1.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon-JCO2.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon-JCO3.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon-JCO4.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon-JCO5.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon-JCO6.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon-JCO7.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon-JCO8.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon-JCO9.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon-JCO10.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon-JCO11.png"],
                  nil];

//     Initialize and configure the carousel

carouselId = 2;
journalCarousel = [[iCarousel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake ( 10, 340, 748, 240)];
journalCarousel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
journalCarousel.type = iCarouselTypeLinear;
journalCarousel.delegate = self;
journalCarousel.dataSource = self;

[self.view addSubview:journalCarousel];
```

EDIT: While debugging I notice that when I have 6 images the function below is called every time and the index value goes from 0 to 5, but when I have more than 6 images the same function is not called for each image, the index values are 0,2,8,9.

```
- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(ReflectionView *)view
{
        UIImage *image = [journalCarouselItems objectAtIndex:index];
        UIButton *button = [[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height)] autorelease];
        [button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        button.titleLabel.font = [button.titleLabel.font fontWithSize:50];
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0f;
        button.tag=index;

        [view addSubview:button];

        return view;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the controller code so we can see what may be wrong in the code?  Right now we just have an error, which is not helpful without code to look at.

Comment: carouselId = 2;
    journalCarousel = [[iCarousel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake ( 10, 340, 748, 240)];
journalCarousel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    journalCarousel.type = iCarouselTypeLinear;
journalCarousel.delegate = self;
journalCarousel.dataSource = self;

    [self.view addSubview:journalCarousel];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue may be coming from the initial declaration of the `journalCarouselItems` array.  That error message means that you're sending an objectAtIndex: messages to an object of type NSString (or possibly CFString). You are then expecing your `journalCarouselItems` to be an array, but it is probably being released (almost certainly autoreleased) too early and that by the time the method above is called the memory that was being pointed at by `journalCarouselItems` now holds something different.

Try `retain`ing the array at the very end of its declaration to ensure it stays at the correct memory location.

```
journalCarouselItems = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon-JCO1.png"],
                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon-JCO2.png"],
                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon-JCO3.png"],
                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon-JCO4.png"],
                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon-JCO5.png"],
                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon-JCO6.png"],
                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon-JCO7.png"],
                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon-JCO8.png"],
                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon-JCO9.png"],
                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon-JCO10.png"],
                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon-JCO11.png"],
              nil] retain];
```